# How to copy object values from safari's console

Tags: javascript, web, safari

Refer this image.
I have logged an object in safari console, but can't copy it by right clicking
Is there any way to copy the object
[image]

Comment: use JSON.stringify(cssObject), and copy then paste in vscode. 
For better visibility in vscode remove double quote from pasted object if present and format document.

Comment: `copy(cssObject)` might work I guess.